# Should datasource xml and meta files be tracked by git?

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

Do these files need to be tracked?

```
new file:   .idea/compiler.xml
new file:   .idea/dataSources/d00e28b9-8967-4490-968b-773416d579a0.xml
new file:   .idea/dataSources/d00e28b9-8967-4490-968b-773416d579a0/storage_v2/_src_/database/matt.FAczAA.meta
new file:   .idea/dataSources/d00e28b9-8967-4490-968b-773416d579a0/storage_v2/_src_/database/matt.FAczAA/schema/public.abK9xQ.meta
new file:   .idea/encodings.xml
new file:   .idea/misc.xml
new file:   RestService.iml
```

I'm using a .gitignore file I found on stackoverflow for idea projects.

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/intellij

### Intellij ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and Webstorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff:
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
.idea/dataSources.ids
.idea/dataSources.xml
.idea/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/dynamic.xml
.idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
.idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

### Intellij Patch ###
# Comment Reason: https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186#issuecomment-215987721

# *.iml
# modules.xml

# Mac
.DS_Store

# Maven
log/
target/
```

I updated it to get rid of those files:

```
.idea/

## File-based project format:
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:
# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

*.iml
modules.xml
```

Comment: Please use the official IntelliJ documentation, which is kept up to date: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Answer (score -1):

No, you can place them under .gitignore.

The .idea folder is IDE related and stores temporary informations like opened windows inside the idea tool but those informations are not needed.

Your gitignore seems good to me

Comment: wouldn't it be better to just ignore the .idea folder?